# Telerik AJAX radComboBox. Getting SelectedValue from second comboBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, combobox, telerik

I’m trying to populate one Telerik AJAX radComboBox from the results of another i.e.

1. comboBox1 – autocompletes and user selects an item
2. comboBox2 – user
   selects. Loads on demand.  Uses the selected value from comboBox1 to
   populate itself.

The problem is that I can’t get the selected value of combobox1

Markup

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="comboBox1" runat="server" 
                 EnableLoadOnDemand="True" 
                 MarkFirstMatch="False" 
                 onitemsrequested="comboBox1_ItemsRequested" >
            </telerik:RadComboBox>

   <telerik:RadComboBox ID="comboBox2" runat="server" 
                 EnableLoadOnDemand="True" 
                 MarkFirstMatch="False" 
                 onitemsrequested="comboBox2_ItemsRequested" >
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

C#

```
protected void comboBox1_ItemsRequested(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    //.. populate this combo
}

protected void comboBox2_ItemsRequested(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    string test = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
    //.. test is empty. Why?? 
}
```

Frustratingly I can’t get the selected value.  The problem might be that the page isn’t actually posting back (must be part of the issue) so that selected value has no opportunity to be set. So I have written the code to get around this

Markup

```
   <telerik:RadComboBox ID="comboBox1" runat="server" 
                 EnableLoadOnDemand="True" 
                 MarkFirstMatch="False" 
                 onitemsrequested="comboBox1_ItemsRequested" 
  onclientselectedindexchanged="OnClientSelectedIndexChanged">
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidClientId" />

   <telerik:RadComboBox ID="comboBox2" runat="server" 
                 EnableLoadOnDemand="True" 
                 MarkFirstMatch="False" 

                 onitemsrequested="comboBox2_ItemsRequested" >
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

JQuery

```
function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {

         var item = eventArgs.get_item();
        var value = item.get_value();
        $("[ID$='hidClientId']").val(value);
}
```

C#

```
protected void comboBox2_ItemsRequested(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    string test = hidClientId. Value;
    //.. test is empty. Why?? 
}
```

This would seem to me to have bypassed the postback issue but it still doesn’t work.

Does anyone know how to get the value of one radComboBox from another? Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Where are you setting the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`?

Comment: I'm not explicitly setting it because it's loading on demand. I'm adding them as list items i.e. 

    foreach (Reference item in items) { cbClient.Items.Add(new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem { Text = item.Description, Value = item.Value }); }

Comment: It sounds like the selections are overwritten and replaced by new list items before you reach that point in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you cannot access the other controls on the page, is because the RadComboBox performs an Async request for the items and as such the other controls on the page are not accessible.

Try handling the `OnClientItemsRequesting` event, making use of the context object (that is passed to the server-side code) to send the selected value of the first combo.

**Markup**

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function OnClientItemsRequesting(sender, eventArgs) {

            var comboBox1 = $find('<%= comboBox1.ClientID %>');
            var value = comboBox1.get_value();

            var context = eventArgs.get_context();
            context["ComboBox1Value"] = value;
        }

    </script>

</telerik:RadCodeBlock>

<telerik:RadComboBox ID="comboBox1" runat="server" 
    MarkFirstMatch="False">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Item 1" Value="0" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Item 2" Value="1" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>

<telerik:RadComboBox ID="comboBox2" runat="server" 
            EnableLoadOnDemand="True" 
            MarkFirstMatch="False" 
            onitemsrequested="comboBox2_ItemsRequested"
            OnClientItemsRequesting="OnClientItemsRequesting">
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void comboBox2_ItemsRequested(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = e.Context["ComboBox1Value"].ToString();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this @jdavies but i don't think it works.OnClientItemsRequesting is too early to get the value. I've changed it to OnClientSelectedIndexChanged but then the context isn't available. Looks like it's something like this

Comment: In my example above, the `OnClientItemsRequesting` function is associated with `comboBox2`. Therefore any selection should have already been made from `comboBox1` (or it would use the default selected item)? I'm not sure what you mean about it being fired too early, am I missing something?

Comment: Apologies for that. I had the event on the wrong comboBox. works perfectly. Thanks for that